# Isn't the word "experience" wrongly used in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, do-support

> Friend: Have you ever flirted with a female cop?
>
> Me: Nope.
>
> Friend: I have done that **experience**.

I think *experience* is the wrong word here. What else should he have said?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***Experience*** is fine. The problem is the *done*. You don't do an experience<sup>1</sup>. You *have* an experience.

> I have **had** that experience.

That's what he should have said. Or, alternatively, just relied on *do* alone:

> Yes, I have **done that**.

Or, indeed, just use the *have*:

> Yes, **I have**.

While there's other options, there was nothing wrong with using *experience*. The only problem is that you don't *do* experiences.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Well, there is a use of *experience* that has emerged in recent years that you would use *to do* to talk about, but it's not actually relevant here.

Comment: Yes experience is not done, it's felt. But does I have had that experience make any sense in this context?

Comment: Experience does not mean skill. It means, well, *having experienced* it. If you sit through a film, you've *experienced seeing the film*. If you've been to Niagara Falls, that's *an experience* you've had.

Comment: Yes. But experience is something that happens to you not what you do. How can flirting be an experience? I'm confused.

Comment: No, experience doesn't have anything to say about who does what. If you climb Everest, then you have "experienced climbing Everest", and if someone says "have you ever climbed Everest", you can say "I have had that experience".

Comment: If the question was. Have you ever been in relationship with a female cop?  Can I still say, 'I have had the experience'? That is, _I have had the experience of being in a relationship with a female cop_

Comment: @Stewart Gilligan Griffin: "I have had the experience of **x**" is a richer statement than "I have done **x**." "I have had that experience", in this context, not only says that he has done that activity (flirting), but he has gone through the whole experience of the activity and everything that goes with it including her reaction and any subsequent events.

Comment: Indeed, "I have had that experience" is often very loaded with tone. It can mean all sorts of things, but the basic meaning of the words remains in any case.

Comment: Or, you could say "experience" *is* the problem here. "I have done that" works just fine. It's even more colloquial, I'd say. The best option is probably simply "I have", though.

Comment: @only_pro: Those options are all mentioned in the answer...

Comment: @SamBC One last question.  Is there a nuance between I've had that experience/I've experienced it?

Comment: There is also: “I’ve done that **before**”.